# After installing R Recommended package, kernel shows error when I use Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, package, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

```
Package web https://anaconda.org/r/r-recommended

kernel error
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 457, in wrapper

    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run

    value = future.result()

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result

    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run

    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 62, in post

    kernel_id=kernel_id))

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run

    value = future.result()

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result

    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run

    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session

    kernel_name)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run

    value = future.result()

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result

    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1014, in run

    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session

    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1008, in run

    value = future.result()

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 232, in result

    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 282, in wrapper

    yielded = next(result)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel

    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel

    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel

    **kw)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel

    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel

    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__

    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\LIU\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child

    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
```

Comment: That error means it can't find the R executable. Can you find `ir` in the output of `jupyter kernelspec list`, and see what's in the `kernel.json` file there.